# How to fix "OverflowError: Unsupported UTF-8 sequence length when encoding string"

Tags: python, pandas, utf-8, to-json

Getting follwoing error while converting pandas dataframe to json

> OverflowError: Unsupported UTF-8 sequence length when encoding string

this is code to

```
        bytes_to_write = data.to_json(orient='records').encode()
        fs = s3fs.S3FileSystem(key=aws_access_key_id, secret=aws_secret_access_key)
        with fs.open(file, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(bytes_to_write)
```

While data which trying to convert to json contain more `utf-8` codes

How to solve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As this [answer suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8422243/overflowerror-unsupported-utf-8-sequence-length-when-encoding-string#comment105608580_14567504), I converted the data-frame using the function `.to_json()` and the `default_handler` parameter, you can find the documentation [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html).

You have to pay attention to the `default_handler=str` parameter so you don't get the mentioned error. You can read the details in the doc above.

```
dataframe.to_json('foo.json', default_handler=str)
```

Please don't forget to consider that the function can output the `json` in differents ways, the `orient='<option>'` parameter specifies that, as the doc says:

```
orient: str
Indication of expected JSON string format.
...
The format of the JSON string:

- ‘split’ : dict like {‘index’ -> [index], ‘columns’ -> [columns], ‘data’ -> [values]}
- ‘records’ : list like [{column -> value}, … , {column -> value}]
- ‘index’ : dict like {index -> {column -> value}}
- ‘columns’ : dict like {column -> {index -> value}}
- ‘values’ : just the values array
- ‘table’ : dict like {‘schema’: {schema}, ‘data’: {data}}

Describing the data, where data component is like orient='records'.
```