# Maximum Recursion Level Reached Converting Pandas Dataframe to Json

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe which contains thousands of rows, and a few columns. I am getting an error when trying to convert it to a json file.

This is the code to convert:

```
sessionAttendance.to_json('SessionAttendance.json')
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
OverflowError: Maximum recursion level reached


                             _id       wondeID  session               updatedAt
0       123456789101112131415161  AA1234567891        AM 2019-06-21 08:05:50.845
1       123456789101112131415162  AA1234567892        AM 2019-06-21 08:05:50.845
2       123456789101112131415163  AA1234567893        AM 2019-06-21 08:05:50.845
3       123456789101112131415164  AA1234567894        AM 2019-06-21 08:05:50.845


[234195 rows x 4 columns]
```

Comment: If you provided a [mcve] with a few lines of data, maybe we could try to reproduce...

Comment: It will not work. Eric (and I) suspect cyclic dependencies. We need all the columns, and need know what they really contain. For example if one column contains a list (not the string of a list representation but a true list), you shall say it, and say how it is built.

Comment: @SergeBallesta They are all objects

Comment: Hmm, building a json from 234195 rows , seem to be resource consuming. How much memory has you system, and what are you OS and Python versions?

Comment: Python 3.7, 16 GB RAM, 64 bit OS x 64 based processer

Comment: I cannot reproduce on my Windows 10 box...  What happen is you drastically reduce the number of rows: `sessionAttendance.iloc[:100].to_json('SessionAttendance.json')` (only first 100 lines)

Comment: @SergeBallesta I got this error - OverflowError: Overlong 2 byte UTF-8 sequence detected when encoding string

Comment: Could the `_id` column be Mongo related? I have just found https://stackoverflow.com/a/14567504/3545273. What gives `sessionAttendance.iloc[:100].to_json('SessionAttendance.json', default_handler=str)`?

Comment: Yes it must be Mongo related, as that is where I'm getting the data from - sessionAttendance.iloc[:100].to_json('SessionAttendance.json', default_handler=str) - didn't produce any errors

Comment: No error is good, but *didn't produce anything* is weird. It should have at least produced a file somewhere...

Comment: @SergeBallesta  Yes - sorry it did produce a file, so I think you fixed it. Thanks so much

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It seems to be related to the way Mongo formats its `_id` fields which are not correctly processed by the `json` module. A workaround is to set `default_handler=str` to force the json formatter to use a string representation for any unwanted type:

```
sessionAttendance.to_json('SessionAttendance.json', default_handler=str)
```

Disclaimer: credit should be given to that other [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14567504/3545273)

Answer (score 0):

I found same error when i using `Ray`.

The data like this:

```json
{'id': 100, 'tags': ['tag1', 'tag2']}
{'id': 100, 'tags': ['tag1', 'tag2']}
```

when I use `ds.write_json('path-path')` crash the error.

So, i fix the error using tuple or list when call the map.

```py
ds = ray.data.read_json('source.jsonl')

def process_records(records,):
    for i in records['id']:
        records['tags'][i] = tuple(records['tags'][i])

    return records

...
ds.map_batches(process_records)
ds.select_columns(['tags']).write_json('cleaned/', orient='records', lines=True, force_ascii=False, default_handler=str)
```

Answer (score -2):

```
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(1500) # this number can be any limit
```

If it's a table the code above should fix it. If your pandas data frame itself has columns which are objects, you might need to make sure that there are no cyclic dependencies in the object

https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/4873

It could be related to the issue posted above. To get past it, first convert your date time column to a string

`df['updatedAt'] = df['updatedAt'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')`

The converting it to a json should work.

Comment: Thanks Eric, I tried that but it didn't make any difference. How can I check whether there a cyclic dependancies or not?

Comment: Can you post the first few rows of your dataframe?

Comment: Can you post every column?

Comment: Thanks @Eric Yang. I just tried converting the date/time column to a string but it's still coming up with the same error

Comment: Can you post the data types of each column?

Comment: what is the output of: 
    sessionAttendance.dtypes

Comment: They are all objects

Comment: What happens if you try to convert the first 10 rows to JSON?

Comment: I tried this - sessionAttendance.iloc[:10].to_json('SessionAttendance.json') - and got this error - OverflowError: Overlong 2 byte UTF-8 sequence detected when encoding string